# How test Web service method in the browser which has primitive parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have web service which have two methods. 1 method has non-primitive parameter like string,date... another one has primitive parameter

1st method i can test like this `http://localhost/Integration/CustomerManagement.asmx/UpdateToPaid?customerNumber=000001&startDate=01/01/2012&endDate=12/31/2012`
which is working fine.

2nd method has "Customer object" has an object parameter in the web method. I don't know how to test this?. I have to WAST (Web Application Stress Tool) to test this method.

`http://localhost/Integration/CustomerManagement.asmx?op=CreateUpdateIndividualCustomer`

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateUpdateIndividualCustomer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <customerDetails>
        <CustomerNumber>string</CustomerNumber>
        <FirstName>string</FirstName>
        <LastName>string</LastName>
        <Email>string</Email>
        <JobTitle>string</JobTitle>
        <Status>string</Status>
        <Indicator>string</Indicator>
        <Password>string</Password>
        <PasswordQuestion>string</PasswordQuestion>
        <PasswordAnswer>string</PasswordAnswer>
        <IsApproved>boolean</IsApproved>
        <FullName>string</FullName>
        <ExtendedStatus>string</ExtendedStatus>
      </customerDetails>
    </CreateUpdateIndividualCustomer>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelop
```

Comment: I'd just make a new console app, add a reference to the web service, and call it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use a unit test framework to test a service. It allows me to write unit tests which pretty much look like the code my customers would use to call the service. This helps with usability, since I have to use my own web service API in order to test the service.

Comment: That is true. But how can I do load testing?

Comment: You were doing load testing in a browser? Anyway, if you have Visual Studio Ultimate, you can create a load test that runs the unit test according to your specifications (number of users, LAN emulation, etc).